# Lucene security search asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene, lucene.net

Im hoping this would be a really easy question for someone....

Basically we are indexing security information against my documents in lucene.net, the information is stored in 2 document fields called **viewuserids** and **viewroleids**, so when we construct a query - only documents which the user has view access to are returned.

The required functionality for a query is that we want only documents to be returned if a user belongs to the roles stored in **viewroleids** (this bit is working fine), however if **viewuserids** field contains any ids (the field may not contain any values) on the index the  **viewroleids** should be ignored and only users who are present in **viewuserids** should be able to see the document.

As mentioned above the role part works as expected, but we need a little help on constucting a term query in the API to take into account the **viewuserids** (effectively overriding the **viewroleids** query. This is what we have so far:

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
foreach (int roleId in roleIds)
{
      bq.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("viewroleid", roleId.ToString())),BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}
bq.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("viewuserid", User.Id.ToString())), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

NOTE:
both fields are stored in the index untokenised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but here is one:

Add a field "hasviewuserids", which contains "TRUE" if a document has any viewuserids associated with it, and "FALSE" if not.  So if, for example, the current userid is 3 and is in roles 5 and 6, the query would look like:

```
(+(viewroleids:5 viewroleids:6) +hasviewuserids:FALSE) OR viewuserids:3
```

Comment: beautiful, I almost got there myself:
I assumed I would need to search on a field that was blank (which i dont think you can do in lucene) so I changed the index builder to add a zzz-zzz-zzz value into viewuserid if no users were present, that way I could query the index like this (using your syntax):
 (+(viewroleid:24 viewroleid:6) +viewuserid:ZZZ-ZZZ-ZZZ) OR viewuserid:100079

Comment: I just need to write this using the API now...gulp

Comment: for anyone interested i implemented like this: